# Is it possible to keyframe f-curve?

Tags: image

SO I have an animation I'm trying to get going and what I'm trying to do is edit specific frames in an f-curve for a shape key. Every time I try to add a keyframe I get an "F-Curve with path 'key_blocks["Talking Up"].value[0]' cannot be keyframed, ensure that it is not locked or sampled, and try removing F-Modifiers
"...Is there a way to convert the f-curve into keyframes?